# How exactly does AFNetworking work?

Tags: ios, multithreading, afnetworking

hi all， I've played with `ASIHttpRequest`, AFNetworking for a while, today, I try to read the source code of AFNetworking more deeply, it's really a powerful and well designed network framework, now I got several questions to ask:
1, the `AFJSONRequestOperation`:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:kMobileBind parameters:paramsBase];

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {  //successblock   } fail:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON){  //failblock   }
```

after this, the operation created and success block and fail block are set to it, then we start the operation, it starts the `NSURLconnection` in a singleton thread,

```
[self performSelector:@selector(operationDidStart) onThread:[[self class] networkRequestThread] withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO modes:[self.runLoopModes allObjects]];
```

inside operationDidStart：

```
 [self.lock lock];
 NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    for (NSString *runLoopMode in self.runLoopModes) {
        [self.connection scheduleInRunLoop:runLoop forMode:runLoopMode];
        [self.outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:runLoop forMode:runLoopMode];
    }
[self.connection start];
[self.lock unlock];
```

this operation runs and `NSURLconnection` callbacks get called,

```
 - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)__unused connection {
self.responseData = [self.outputStream propertyForKey:NSStreamDataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey];
[self.outputStream close];
[self finish];
self.connection = nil;
}

- (void)finish {
    self.state = AFHTTPOperationFinishedState;
}
```

the finish method set the state of operation, and it uses KVO tech, to finished the operation: 
I didn't see observeValueForKeyPath and [obj addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"isFinished" options:0 context:NULL]; how does KVO work?

setState:

```
    [self willChangeValueForKey:newStateKey];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:oldStateKey];
    _state = state;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:oldStateKey];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:newStateKey];



- (BOOL)isFinished {
    return self.state == AFHTTPOperationFinishedState;
}
```

then I got stuck here, I find the setcallblock fund, but can't understant how does self.completionBlock be called:

```
- (void)setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success

   failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure

{
    self.completionBlock = ^ {
    if ([self isCancelled]) {
        return;
    }

    if (self.error) {
        if (failure) {
            dispatch_async(self.failureCallbackQueue ? self.failureCallbackQueue : dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                failure(self, self.error);
            });
        }
    } else {
        if (success) {
            dispatch_async(self.successCallbackQueue ? self.successCallbackQueue : dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                success(self, self.responseData);
            });
        }
    }
};
```

}

May be I did read the code carefully, but it really gets me confused, any one who has experience on AFNetworking pls explains this framework,

One more question, the network requests are ran on a shared thread, will it slow down the request?

I do wanna improve my skill in mutilthread programming, and I need samples and suggestions, I've read apple's docs, and made some simple demos, haven't tried on a big project or code a robust framework or model, how do I start? many thanks

Answer (score 1):

`completionBlock` is a property of `AFJSONRequestOperation`'s **superclass**, `NSOperation`. It is executed when the operation **completes**.